# Condense Chrome extension buttons

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Chrome extensions are starting to take up real estate in my browser window:

[image]

Is it possible to hide these buttons or display them more economically?

Comment: You can drag the extension bar to the right to have the UI create a drop down link of your installed extension.  You could also just right click and choose **hide extension**

Answer (score 39, accepted):

### Resizing the address bar

It seems like you can simply *drag* your address bar bigger:
[image: A double-arrow appears when hovering over the right edge of the address bar]
Then your icons will be collapsed:
[image: The extension icons are collapsed to a little arrow]
[Source](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=Xpx7m8_3MOo)

---

### Hiding single buttons

You can hide single icons, by right-clicking on them and choosing **Hide button**:
[image]

You can then re-enable the button through the Extensions menu:
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to put them in something like a dropdown menu? It would  be a hassle to have to re-show the button each time I want to use an extension.

Comment: Found this useful for enabling and disbaling extensions in a few clicks, without the need to visit chrome://extensions -- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/extension-switch/gnphfcibcphlpedmaccolafjonmckcdn