# All of my Chrome extension buttons have disappeared

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 now, and a few days ago, I noticed that all of the buttons for my installed Chrome extensions have disappeared. The extensions are still installed (and still enabled), but their buttons are all gone. Is this a bug, or have all extension buttons been removed as part of the latest update to Google Chrome?

Comment: Is there any way to manually enable/disable Chrome extension buttons?

Comment: It appears that all of the extension buttons were replaced with a drop-down list that contains the extension buttons. (I hope this wasn't done intentionally as part of an update to Chrome - it only makes it harder to find individual extensions, without saving any space on the page.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like what's happened is you've clicked a little bar that is usually between the far right of the address bar (just to the right of the bookmark star) and where your extensions used to be (probably to the left of a little double arrow pointing right).

Assuming that this is what's happened, basically it sounds like you've re-sized the address bar and pushed the extensions out of the way.

If this is the case, click on the horizontal bar up there where I was talking and drag it back to the left and they should re-appear where they're supposed to be.

[image]

Comment: You should provide more information perhaps even screenshots making it clear how to do this.

Comment: [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/pXIcn.png)  -- No idea how to post an actual image embedded.  Doesn't seem to be working in comments.

Comment: @Ramhound See the link in my answer for a more detailed explanation (with screenshots).

Comment: LOL, I feel stupid now.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/435729/85129), in order to make the extension buttons re-appear, you can simply drag the edge of the address bar. This will make all the extension buttons re-appear again!